# What's the different between Mat.at<uchar> and Mat.at<int>

Tags: types, opencv3.0, mat

i had find in web a code which uses the following code

```
cv::VideoCapture frame_capture;
...
cv::Mat frame;
frame_capture.read(frame);
...
std::vector<cv::Mat> bgr_planes;
split(frame, bgr_planes);
...
int curr_pixel = (bgr_planes[0].at<uchar>(row_index,col_index));
...
```

which get the value from the Mat vector and assign it to the variable

when i tried to change `.at<uchar>` by `.at<int>` i've got this error

`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < 
(unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\Open_CV\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 537`

my question is since .at returns an integer why here we have `.at<uchar>`

Answer (score 2):

> since .at returns an integer why here we have .at?

Your premises are wrong:

```
 .at<type>
```

returns a variable of the given type. You then can cast to another type, like "int".

This is equivalent to:

```
uchar original_value = mat.at<uchar>(row, col);
int int_value = original_value;
```

The error means you're going out of bound of the matrix data, because you're indexing an array of uchar (1 byte) as if it was an array of int (4 bytes)